# Recreating "modern" left menu bars in WPF

Tags: wpf, blend

I'm trying to recreate the menu bars that are displayed to the left of the "modern" Windows 10 applications, for example the weather, maps, and search apps.

Currently I have a Menu snapped to the top grid, then within this I have StackPanels that contain two labels - one label with Segoe Assets font for the icon, and then a true label, such as for example "Settings".

Here's my current XML:

```
 <Menu x:Name="mnuLeft" Style="{StaticResource leftMenu}" Background="#FF2B2B2B" Foreground="White" Margin="0,48,349.667,0" Focusable="True" Padding="0" Width="Auto" >
        <Menu.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" LastChildFill="False"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Menu.ItemsPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Width="191" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Label x:Name="label9" Content="&#xE115;" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="48" Width="48" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="18.667" Foreground="White" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
            <Label x:Name="label10" Content="Options" Margin="0,-0.667,0,0.666" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="16" Foreground="White" Height="48" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Width="191" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Label x:Name="label7" Content="&#xE7AC;" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="48" Width="47" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="18.667" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
            <Label x:Name="label8" Content="Status" Margin="0,-0.667,0,0.666" Width="125.659" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="16" Foreground="White" Height="48" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Menu>
```

Basically what I would like is the StackPanel that contains options to be docked to the bottom of the menu, and then the Status docked to the top (More stackpanels being added later). However at the moment they sit centered when the VerticalAlign is set to Stretch, and then sit both at the top when the VerticalAlign is set to top.

I've tried multiple iterations of the setup, including using fixed margin values, which I would like to avoid, as I'd prefer the user to be able to scale the Window.